# Change MapView in GoogleMaps v2 with a checkbox on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, checkbox, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I can't change the map type on my Android Application, everything work fine but this feature is not.

This is a part of the MapActivity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
    this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_fabio);
    options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL)
    .compassEnabled(true)
    .scrollGesturesEnabled(true)
    .zoomGesturesEnabled(true)
    .tiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    MapFragment.newInstance(options);
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                          .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    satellite = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.satellite);
    satellite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                                                   boolean isChecked) {
            if (satellite.isChecked()){
                mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);                  
            }
        }
    });
```

The check is listened but the map doesn't change the view.

Comment: check this it will sure help you. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-google-map-switching-between-map-view-and-satellite-view/

Comment: What exactly doesn't work and how?

Comment: when I click on the checkbox, the view doesn't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have this import:

```
import static com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
```

For changing map type to satellite you should have this line:

```
mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```